# What is preventing a parent's children from being discovered by my code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

Writing a Greasemonkey script that:

1. First collects elements that match a criterion. These are `<a>` tags.
2. Within a simple for loop, it will perform an automated click on each link.
3. Then it will click on another `<a>` link.
4. After that, it will enter some text before submitting the text for server processing.
5. The for loop repeats the sequence until the list is exhausted.

I have figured out how to build the collection of the desired elements, but for some reason, the code is not able to access some child nodes, returning results like `null` and `undefined`.

The problem occurs in this section of code:

```
$(".indeed-apply-button").html();
```

This class is part of the `<a>` tag.

So I have tried to access the child nodes with `querySelector()`, which returns undefined.

I tried using `$();` selector. It will return `[object Object]`. With `.html()` appended, it will return undefined.

The `<a>` tag that I wish to extract from the document is confined within several parent `<div>` tags.
Somewhere in the code within the series of those `<div>` tags exists a point where my code either refuses or is unable to access the child nodes.

The script runs on indeed.com after a job search. It will select each job in the list then click the apply button.
For example, [www.indeed.com/q-programmer-l-maine-jobs.html](https://www.indeed.com/q-programmer-l-maine-jobs.html)

What could cause some elements to not be able to be retrieved, would be a more general question.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var jobList = document.querySelectorAll("a[data-tn-element='jobTitle']");

  function clickThenApply (jobNumber) {
    var jobTitle = $(jobList[jobNumber]).attr("title"); //job name
    var jobLink = $(jobList[jobNumber]).attr("href"); //job link
    jobList[jobNumber].click();
    var apply = $(".indeed-apply-button").html();
    console.log("Job title: " + jobTitle);
    console.log("Job link: " + jobLink);
    console.log("success? " + apply);
    return true;
    }

  for (var i = 0; i < jobList.length; i++) {
  var tog = clickThenApply(i);
  }

});
```

The problem occurs in this section of code:

```
$(".indeed-apply-button").html();
```

This class is part of the `<a>` tag:

```
<a class="indeed-apply-button" href="javascript:void(0);" id="indeed-ia-...">
  <span class="indeed-apply-button-inner" id="indeed-ia-...">
    <span class="indeed-apply-button-label" id="indeed-ia-...">Apply Now</span>
    <span class="indeed-apply-button-cm">
      <img src="....cloudfront.net/indeedapply/s/14096d1/check.png">
    </span>
  </span>
</a>
```

I have tried:

```
document.querySelector("a.indeed-apply-button");
```

It returns null/undefined.

If you could provide any insight into this, I would appreciate it!

Comment: Please add a minimal example of the relevant HTML.

Comment: @connexo, Added  to the question.  Note that he linked to the target page, which is the gold-standard for Tampermonkey questions, and covers many sins.

Comment: Duke Lee, the node is added via AJAX techniques some delay after `jobList[jobNumber].click();`.  You need to code asynchronously or put the `jobList` in a queue.  The pieces have all been addressed here before, I don't have the vim to write a full answer for this right now.

Answer (score 0):

As Brock stated in the comments, the issue is that merely clicking the button doesn't mean every element is there already. A myriad of things can happen asynchronously to trigger this.

Let's get creative. On any application that I've seen, there is either the button you're after, or a `.view-apply-button`. We're going to use this as our signal that something has happened.

First off, we're going to be returning promises from here on. Get a library if it's not built-in.

```
function clickThenApply(jobNumber) {
  var jobTitle = $(jobList[jobNumber]).attr("title"); //job name
  var jobLink = $(jobList[jobNumber]).attr("href"); //job link

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // Do the click
    jobList[jobNumber].click();

    // Set our interval. This will test whether there is either of the buttons
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
      var applyButton = $(".indeed-apply-button");
      if (applyButton.length > 0) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        return resolve({
          name: jobTitle,
          link: jobLink,
          apply: applyButton
        });
      var toSiteButton = $(".view-apply-button");
      if (toSiteButton.length > 0) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        return resolve({
          name: jobTitle,
          link: jobLink,
          visit: applyButton
        });
    }, 100);
    var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
      if (interval) clearInterval(interval);
      reject({
        name: jobTitle,
        link: jobLink,
        error: "Button not found after 5000ms"
      });
    }, 5000);
  });
}
```

The code is deliberately verbose so it is readable and its intent is clear. Every 100ms, I'm checking if either of the buttons exist. If they do, I resolve the `Promise` with the data (which you can then process elsewhere). If after 5s I still have nothing, I return an error.

I have left some of the things up to you to do, however:

- You will need to chain these calls in order to make it work, as clicking multiple buttons simultaneously will be hell on Earth
- You will also need to make sure the button does not disappear while you're using it